# Memory stability of a C++ application in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, memory, memory-leaks

I want to verify the memory stability of a C++ application I wrote and compiled for Linux.
It is a network application that responds to remote clients connectings in a rate of 10-20 connections per second.
On long run, memory was rising to 50MB, eventhough the app was making calls to delete...

Investigation shows that Linux does not immediately free memory. So here are my questions :

How can force Linux to free memory I actually freed? At least I want to do this once to verify memory stability.
Otherwise, is there any reliable memory indicator that can report memory my app is actually holding?

Comment: Smart pointer will not solve the issue here as the question is not exactly about how to solve memory leak. It is rather about verification and detction of it in presence of this Linux process of caching memory and not immediately releasing it to the kernel. Even with a smart pointer, at one pt of time we need to call delete, and then you wo'nt see the memory go down so you will falsely think your program is leaking memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are seeing is most likely not a memory leak at all.  Operating systems and malloc/new heaps both do very complex accounting of memory these days.  This is, in general, a *very good thing.*  Chances are any attempt on your part to force the OS to free the memory will only hurt both your application performance and overall system performance.

To illustrate:

1. The Heap reserves several areas of virtual memory for use.  None of it is actually committed (backed by physical memory) until malloc'd.
2. You allocate memory.  The Heap grows accordingly. You see this in task manager.
3. You allocate more memory on the Heap.  It grows more.
4. You free memory allocated in Step 2.  The Heap cannot shrink, however, because the memory in #3 is still allocated, and Heaps are unable to compact memory (it would invalidate your pointers).
5. You malloc/new more stuff.  This may get tacked on *after* memory allocated in step #3, because it cannot fit in the area left open by free'ing #2, or because it would be inefficient for the Heap manager to scour the heap for the block left open by #2.  (depends on the Heap implementation and the chunk size of memory being allocated/free'd)

So is that memory at step #2 now dead to the world?  Not necessarily.  For one thing, it will probably get reused eventually, once it becomes efficient to do so.  In cases where it isn't reused, the Operating System itself may be able to use the CPU's Virtual Memory features (the TLB) to "remap" the unused memory right out from under your application, and assign it to another application -- on the fly.  The Heap is aware of this and usually manages things in a way to help improve the OS's ability to remap pages.

**These are valuable memory management techniques that have the unmitigated side effect of rendering fine-grained memory-leak detection via Process Explorer mostly useless.**  If you want to detect small memory leaks in the heap, then you'll need to use runtime heap leak-detection tools.  Since you mentioned that you're able to build on Windows as well, I will note that Microsoft's CRT has adequate leak-checking tools built-in.  Instructions for use found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1(v=vs.100).aspx

There are also open-source replacements for malloc available for use with GCC/Clang toolchains, though I have no direct experience with them.  I think on Linux **Valgrind** is the preferred and more reliable method for leak-detection anyway.  (and in my experience easier to use than MSVCRT Debug).

Comment: I am frustrated that there is no indicator measuring the actual memory used by a process. I was hoping to monitor my app on the long run and judging if it can stay running for many days without bringing the system down.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the industry standard approach is to not even try to create a perfectly leak-proof app, and instead to "shorten the process lifespan."  Many server apps in particular (such as apache, mysql, etc) work by having a single process manager that spawns worker processes.  The workers will kill themselves after some period of time, and then the parent will spawn a new process in their place.

Because of how operating systems sandbox processes, this is a very reliable way to prevent long term memory or resource leakages.  But it also complicates program design.

Comment: Hi, the stability of apach and mysql was indeed one of my puzzles till i discovered the exact behavior you described. The number of processes for apach and mysql is dynamic, at least on Linux. It is really a big complication for me to do a fork. maybe even theoretically impossible. I'm looking at how I can transform all dynamically allocated data into an Object Pool.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using valgrind with memcheck tool or any other profiling tool for memory leaks

from Valgrind's page:

> **Memcheck**
>
> detects memory-management problems, and is aimed primarily at
>   C and C++ programs. When a program is run under Memcheck's
>   supervision, all reads and writes of memory are checked, and calls to
>   malloc/new/free/delete are intercepted. As a result, Memcheck can
>   detect if your program:
>
> - Accesses memory it shouldn't (areas not yet allocated, areas that have been freed, areas past the end of heap blocks, inaccessible areas
>     of the stack).
> - Uses uninitialised values in dangerous ways.
> - Leaks memory.
> - Does bad frees of heap blocks (double frees, mismatched frees).
> - Passes overlapping source and destination memory blocks to memcpy() and related functions.
>
> Memcheck reports these errors as soon as they occur, giving the source
>   line number at which it occurred, and also a stack trace of the
>   functions called to reach that line. Memcheck tracks addressability at
>   the byte-level, and initialisation of values at the bit-level. As a
>   result, it can detect the use of single uninitialised bits, and does
>   not report spurious errors on bitfield operations. Memcheck runs
>   programs about 10--30x slower than normal. Cachegrind
>
> **Massif**
>
> Massif is a heap profiler. It performs detailed heap profiling by
>   taking regular snapshots of a program's heap. It produces a graph
>   showing heap usage over time, including information about which parts
>   of the program are responsible for the most memory allocations. The
>   graph is supplemented by a text or HTML file that includes more
>   information for determining where the most memory is being allocated.
>   Massif runs programs about 20x slower than normal.

Using valgrind is as simple as running application with desired switches and give it as an input of valgrind:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck ./myapplication -f foo -b bar
```

Comment: Whilst this is definitely a good thing to do, I'm not sure we know if 50MB is unreasonable for the application. It may well be that 50MB is the peak memory usage, but average usage is lower. And over long periods, it doesn't get bigger.

Comment: Memory is increasing. Now it is at 100 MB. I am lucky that my app is compilable on Windows. Using taskmgr memory graph is really stable : it is a straight line. Valgrind did not detect any memory leak. Actually Ido'nt have memory leak. I free all the memory that I allocate for evry connection. I do'nt have stale connections.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Agree. Without seeing the code, we can't guess problem. Sometimes memory leaks may be such virulent that observations may not expose problem. It may be a very slowly growing leak. When your application is running for a long long time (days or weeks) you will see an unreasonable amount of memory. (In my case it was 400MB for a program which uses several megabytes of memory)

Comment: @charfeddine: Of course, you MAY have a leak in some linux-dependant piece of code! ;)

If valgrind shows no leak, then that's good. You have no leaks. 

Also, it may be that you are suffering from memory fragmentation - in which case my suggestion of using mmap to isolate certain sections of memory allocations from others, may help. That is, if it's actually going to be a problem. 100MB isn't a whole lot in a modern machine - my home computer has 16GB of RAM, and I have some machines here at work with hundreds of GB.

Answer (score 2):

I very much doubt that anything beyond wrapping `malloc` and `free`  [or `new` and `delete` ] with another function can actually get you anything other than very rough estimates.

One of the problems is that the memory that is freed can only be released if there is a long contiguous chunk of memory. What typically happens is that there are "little bits" of memory that are used all over the heap, and you can't find a large chunk that can be freed.

It's highly unlikely that you will be able to fix this in any simple way.

And by the way, your application is probably going to need those 50MB later on when you have more load again, so it's just wasted effort to free it.

(If the memory that you are not using is needed for something else, it will get swapped out, and pages that aren't touched for a long time are prime candidates, so if the system runs low on memory for some other tasks, it will still reuse the RAM in your machine for that space, so it's not sitting there wasted - it's just you can't use 'ps' or some such to figure out how much ram your program uses!)

As suggested in a comment: You can also write your own memory allocator, using `mmap()` to create a "chunk" to dole out portions from. If you have a section of code that does a lot of memory allocations, and then ALL of those will definitely be freed later, to allocate all those from a separate lump of memory, and when it's all been freed, you can put the mmap'd region back into a "free `mmap` list", and when the list is sufficiently large, free up some of the `mmap` allocations [this is in an attempt to avoid calling mmap LOTS of times, and then `munmap` again a few millisconds later]. However, if you EVER let one of those memory allocations "escape" out of your fenced in area, your application will probably crash (or worse, not crash, but use memory belonging to some other part of the application, and you get a very strange result somewhere, such as one user gets to see the network content supposed to be for another user!)

Comment: If he can wrap all of his allocations in a custom allocator, which is not used for anything else, it's not that difficult to write the allocator to dole out chunks from a `mmap`ped space, which it later frees.  (But as you said, it's probably not worth it, as he'll almost certainly need the memory later anyway.)

Comment: If I understand well, I do'nt have anyway to easily verify the memory stability of my application except by using a custom that would be able to report the difference between allocations/deallocations. Tomorrow, I will test on a virtual machine to decrease systeme memory like 512MB then cause my app to run till all that memory is hit, then see what happens, Will Linux begin to give me back RAM memory or will it start swap. I am not even sure how I will validate this latter behavior.

Comment: If the memory is not REALLY used, it will just swap out your unused memory, and never swap it back in, unless it's actually being used again. [This applies whether the memory is ALLOCATED or UNALLOCATED - it makes no difference, it's "access" that counts - of course, nothing should be using unallocated memory]. I'm not sure if the kernel ever tries to "reclaim unused memory" from a process. I suspect it does if it runs low - but it's a waste of time to do that if there is plenty of free memory. Using a VM is a great idea, by the way.

Comment: I am running a VM now, using 256MB of RAM. The memory reached 171MB then went down and is stabilizing at 149 MB. Your thinking was correct, when Linux was about to run low, it released the memory. Memory stabilization is an essential goal to me because I am putting the app into stationnary conditions : the flow of incoming connections is equal to the flow of disconnections such that I have a constant avg of simultaneous connections. So the memory should be stable. But I am very frustrated that one does not have the means to meansure the actual memory in use.

Answer (score 1):

Use valgrind to find memory leaks : valgrind ./your_application

It will list where you allocated memory and did not free it.

I don't think it's a linux problem, but in your application. If you monitor the memory usage with « top » you won't get very precise usages. Try using massif (a tool of valgrind) : valgrind --tool=massif ./your_application to know the real memory usage.

As a more general rule to avoid leaks  in C++ : use smart pointers instead of normal pointers.
Also in many situations, you can use RAII (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) instead of allocating memory with "new".

Comment: valgrind did not detect anything. Also my app is cross plateform and i tested it in Windows. Taskmgr reports a straight memory line. No memory increase. I am about 18 MB while in Linux, now as of writing it is at 137 MB. Tomorrow will use a virtual machine with 512 MB to see what happens when I hit the max.

Comment: This probably means just that the OS caches some memory. Nothing to worry about. As other people said, you can not count top or ps to known how much memory is used. You need a memory profiler.

Answer (score 1):

It is not typical for an OS to release memory when you call `free` or `delete`.  This memory goes back to the heap manager in the runtime library.

If you want to actually release memory, you can use `brk`.  But that opens up a very large can of memory-management worms.  If you directly call `brk`, you had better not call `malloc`.  For C++, you can override `new` to use `brk` directly.

Not an easy task.

Comment: First, overriding `operator new` to use `brk` won't prevent library functions from using `malloc`.  Second, you can't actually use `brk` to free memory unless you have some way of being sure that there is no space being used behind it.  Third, if you do want to allocate and then later free, `mmap` is a far better choice.

Comment: @JamesKanze - good points, all.  For point 2, one would have to do all of the memory management oneself, and that's the point of my answer.  Of course point 1 is a real problem.

Comment: Mybe at this point, I do'nt want to cause Linux to actually release memory. What about a memory indicator that can calculate only the memory I am actually using ?

Comment: Calling `free` may *sometimes* release memory (e.g. by `free` calling `munmap`) back to the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

The latest dlmalloc() has a concept called an mspace (others call it a region).  You can call malloc() and free() against an mspace.  Or you can delete the mspace to free all memory allocated from the mspace at once.  Deleting an mspace will free memory from the process.

If you create an mspace with a connection, allocate all memory for the connection from that mspace, and delete the mspace when the connection closes, you would have no process growth.

If you have a pointer in one mspace pointing to memory in another mspace, and you delete the second mspace, then as the language lawyers say "the results are undefined".