# How to check for memory leaks in a large scale c++ Linux application?

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am currently working on a large scale application project (written in c++) which started from scratch some time ago, and we reached the point when it is mandatory to make a roundup of checks for memory leaks.

The application runs on an Ubuntu Linux, it has a lot of multimedia content, and uses OpenGl, SDL and ffmpeg for various purposes including 3D graph rendering, windows, audio and movie playback. You could think of it as a videogame, although it is not, but the duties of the application could be simplified by considering it a video game.

I am currently a little bit clueless in determining whether we still have memory leaks or not. In the past we had already identified some, and removed them. These days though, the application is nearly complete, and the tests we ran are giving me results which I cant exactly figure out.

First thing I did was to try to run the application through Valgrind... unfortunately then application crashes when running in a valgrind environment. The crash in "non-deterministic" since it crashes in various different places. So I gave up with Valgrind to easily identify the source of potential leaks, and ended up using two Linux  commands: free and top.

free is being used for probing system memory usage while the application is running

top is being used with the '-p' option, to probe the application process memory usage while running.

Output form top and free is being dumped into files for post-processing. I made up two graphs with the data which are linked at the bottom of the question.

The test case is very simple: data about memory is being probed once the application has already been launched and it is waiting for commands. Then I start a sequence of commands which repeatedly does always the same thing. The application is expected to load a whole lot multimedia data into RAM, and then download it.

Unfortunately the graph is not showing me what I was expecting. Memory usage grows through 3 different steps and then stops. Memory is apparently never released, which hinted me that there was a HUGE memory leak. that would be perfectly fine, since it would mean that very likely we were not freeing up memory eaten up by media stuff.

But after the first three steps... memory usage is stable... there arent any more huge steps... just slight up and down which correspond to the expected data loading and unloading. The unexpected here is that the data which is supposed to be loaded/unloaded makes up for hundredths of megabytes of RAM, instead the up and downs make of for just a handful of megabytes (lets say 8-10 MB).

I am currently pretty clueless in interpreting these data.

Anyone has some hints or suggestions? What am I missing? Is the method I am using for checking the presence of macroscopic memory leaks completely wrong? DO you know any other (preferably free) tool other than Valgrind for checking memory leaks?

[System Memory Usage Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJOCW.png)

[Process Memory Usage Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZM4Z.png)

Comment: Short answer, Valgrind. Also have a look at Electric Fence though.

Comment: The memory usage will only keep stepping up if you keep doing memory allocations (often in a loop). You need to find out what's happening at those big steps.

Comment: What allocator are you using? Often, unless we are dealing with huge chunks of memory, regular libc allocators rarely return the memory to the OS even when you call `free` (`delete`), keeping it ready for use in future allocations. Still, the fact that your executable crashes when running under valgrind isn't a good sign...

Comment: What you are probably seeing is some initial memory fragmentation, that is causing the allocator to have to grab more memory since it can't find a chunk of memory of the right size, but after a while, enough memory gets allocated that this is no longer a problem.

Comment: How large is your application? How many classes, how many millions of source lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all...

> and we reached the point when it is mandatory to make a roundup of checks for memory leaks.

This, actually, is a **problem of methodology**. Correctness should be the *primary goal* of any software piece and not an afterthought.

I will suppose though that you now realize this and how much easier it would have been to identify the problems had you been running an instrumented unit test at each commit.

---

So, what to do now ?

- Runtime detection:

  - Try to make Valgrind work, you probably have some environmental issues
  - Try [ASan](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html), [ThreadSan](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html) and [MemSan](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html); they are not trivial to setup under Linux but oh so impressive!
  - Try instrumented builds: [tcmalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) includes a [heap-checker](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/heap_checker.html) for example
  - ...
- Compile time detection:

  - Turn on the warnings (preferably with `-Werror`) (not specific to your issue)
  - Use static analysis, such as [Clang's](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), it may spot unpaired allocation routines
  - ...
- Human detection:

  - Code reviews: make sure all resources are allocated within RAII classes
  - ...

*Note: using only RAII classes helps removing memory leaks, but does not help with dangling references. Thankfully, detecting dangling references is what ASan does.*

---

And once you have patched all the issues, make sure that this becomes part of the process. Changes should be reviewed and tested, always, so that rotten eggs are culled immediately rather than left to stink up the code base.

Comment: ASAN is available in the future GCC 4.8 (i.e. the current GCC trunk), so it could be worthwhile to compile the latest GCC trunk and to compile the original poster's huge software using that GCC trunk with ASAN enabled.

Comment: "This, actually, is a problem of methodology. Correctness should be the primary goal of any software piece and not an afterthought."

Comment: @Matthieu -  I undertand your statement, and I pretty much agree with you. That's the theory about software engineering which can be applied in the ideal world. Unfortunately in the real world you (or the company you work for) find yourself in a situation where the ideal methodology cannot be applied completely. In my real world scenario, each developer has performed tests of their own units, and removed his own memory leaks. But when integration arrives, which is the stage we are at now, other issues arise. Which are the ones we are facing these days.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Ah, great to know indeed. I was aware of the idea of porting it, but did not know it had been achieved already!

Comment: @BroneAshura: liveness of some memory object is a *global* (non-modular) property of the program, so having each developer dealing with only his own memory leaks is not enough.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: While I agree with you, I can understand that in the case of modular development you would first test the modules in isolation before bringing them together.

Comment: I accepted the answer a little bit late ... but using tcmalloc proved to be the right way to find the leak without using valgrind, which ended being into the ffmpeg library.

Comment: @BaroneAshura: No worries, I am glad you managed to locate the issue, it can be quite a pain especially when 3rd-party libraries are involved.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of giving up on Valgrind, you should instead work with them and try to

- get rid of the bugs you encountered in Valgrind
- get your app thoroughly tested and debugged with the updated Valgrind.

Saying you gave up on Valgrind which is *the* solution to your problem isn't helping really...

Valgrind is the tool we all use to check for memory-leaks and threading issues under linux.

In the end, it's definitely better to invest time in figuring out "why Valgrind doesn't work with my app" rather than looking for alternate solutions. Valgrind is a proved and tested tool, but not perfect. And it beats the alternative methods by a long, long shot.

The Valgrind page says it's better to submit bugs to Bugzilla, but it's actually better to ask around on https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/valgrind-users if anyone saw such issues before and what to do in such a situation. Worst-case scenario - they'll tell you to file a bug to bugzilla or file it themselves.

Comment: I cannot believe this is upvoted when Dirk's answer is downvoted.

Comment: As I've already told you, Dirk's answer answers neither the literal question nor the XY interpretation "How do I get around these Valgrind issues", it doesn't even acknowledge the issues. So it gives the impression that the author just didn't read the question. Your answer OTOH acknowledges the issues OP had, though I don't think it's terribly useful in its current form (if you added some of the info you posted in comments, it'd be much better).

Comment: the reason why I temporarily gave up on valgrind is on their faq page: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.crashes The application runs on a custom "PC-like" board, and uses a few custom peripheral whose access is granted by drivers provided by the board manufacturer. When I read the comment in the faq page (after 3 days of headbanging on application crashes in the valgrind environment), I simply turned my head to other investigation techinques, and promised I would go back at valgrind once I know I am leaking memory, to find out where I am leaking it.

Comment: anyway.. in the end... it looks as if there is NO alternative to valgrind... so I will have to find out where/why application crashes while in valgrind. Thanks for directing me to the valgrind-users list. As soon as I get back to work next week I will post there. But I am still interested in finding alternative methods for getting detailed informations about memory usage in Linux, if there are any.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to look at [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org).

And you just may want to start with really simple examples to get a feel for what valgrind reports which can be somewhat verbose.  Consider this simplified example where valgrind exactly what and how much is missing:

```
edd@max:/tmp$ cat valgrindex.cpp 

#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
  double *a = new double[100];
  exit(0);
}
edd@max:/tmp$ g++ -o valgrindex valgrindex.cpp 
edd@max:/tmp$ valgrind ./valgrindex
==15910== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==15910== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==15910== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15910== Command: ./valgrindex
==15910== 
==15910== 
==15910== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15910==     in use at exit: 800 bytes in 1 blocks
==15910==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 800 bytes allocated
==15910== 
==15910== LEAK SUMMARY:
==15910==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15910==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15910==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15910==    still reachable: 800 bytes in 1 blocks
==15910==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15910== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==15910== 
==15910== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15910== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
edd@max:/tmp$
```

Comment: This is the real solution, the OP should revisit Valgrind and not dismiss it so lightly because he had issues with it.

Comment: So he has a buggy up.  Cut it in half, find the leak in the first half etc pp.  How else can you debug a complex app?

Comment: @Shark Maybe so, but this answer does not apply in either case. The issue isn't how to use Valgrind, it's nondetemrinistic crashes when running under Valgrind. And if one thinks it's an instance of the XY problem, then one could try to persuade OP to change the question and provide more detail on the issues with Valgrind.

Comment: Thanks, @Shark. I evidently also disagree with the drive-by shooting and downvoting I am experiencing here (and done by others, of course).

Comment: I had a similar issue, altho with a much smaller app... Valgrind didn't work, I gave up on it and we shipped it... 4 months later, the reason valgrind was crashing on me was fixed and some poor soul that got the "this is seriously buggy" rebounce spent a month with the app and Valgrind. App works fine now. Moral of the story - submit all bugs related to Valgrind to the valgrind team because this is *the* tool we all use to detect memory leaks.

Comment: In the end, it's definitely better to invest time in figuring out "why Valgrind doesn't work" rather than looking for alternate solutions. Valgrind is proved and tested, but not perfect. And it beats the alternative methods by a long, long shot.

Comment: @Pubby: just because he tried doesn't mean Valgrind can't provide him with useful info. I don't see where he got the idea to ask here for alternatives to Valgrind when he already fully-well knows that Valgrind is the answer. Why not go and post this exact same thing on their support boards? I think that will be much more fruitful than this IMO.

Comment: @Shark I'm not sure who you're directing this rant at. At OP? Poor visibility then. At Pubby? Missing a few `@Pubby`s then (and possibly disproportionate). At me? You obviously didn't read my comment then (which I edited for a few minutes, admittedly, though without significantly changing its contents).

Comment: @delnan: nope, just saying that my experience showed that Valgrind shouldn't be given up on because doing so will bite you (or someone else) later... I'm not here to argue or anything, just provide a suggestion. He can listen to it, or figure out his own way out of the mess. But if you bother to ask, take the answer being given to you with some weight, even though you tried it and dismissed it as "too much of a bother to figure out whats going wrong".

Comment: well... it's not that I completely gave up on valgrind. And I did put quite some effort in setting it up with error-suppressions. Whether using valgrind or not is a little bit off-topic since the purpose of the question is really: is there any methodology for checking the "existence" of memory leaks, which does not include valgrind? Pin-pointing the memory leaks then, will require the use of valgrind or similar tools. It has never been the case of "too much of a bother to figure out whats going wrong". I know I will HAVE TO tackle valgrind, maybe not now.

Answer (score 2):

Results from `free` and `top` will not be helpful to you.  I regret that you put effort into constructing graphs for their results.  I've given a good explanation why they are unhelpful in a similar topic here: [Memory stability of a C++ application in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023815/memory-stability-of-a-c-application-in-linux/14024853#14024853).

I will also concur with other answers here that you should probably prioritize troubleshooting the crash you're encountering in Valgrind.  Valgrind is considered very stable at this point, and I have personally run rather complex multi-threaded multimedia SDL/OpenGL/etc. apps through it without issue.  It is much more likely that Valgrind's running environment is exposing likely instabilities in your application.  The crash sounds like a thread race condition crash, though it may also be heap/memory corruption.

What you may want to ask for, then, is advice on how to debug an app that's crashing from within Valgrind's running environment (which is something I don't know the answer to).

Comment: well... the crash appears to happen when trying to display things. I have tried to run the application, completely disabling OpenGL stuff, but still it ends up crashing when in valgrind. Building the graphs was anyway useful, and did not cost me a huge amount of time, just a little bit of scripting and then copy/paste in spreadsheet. Much quicker then being stubborn with valgrind when valgrind faqs say this: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.crashes :( Anyway... I guess I'll have to be stubborn with valgrind anyway :P

Comment: Your application almost certainly has some kind of bug that could very well manifest itself on end user machines.  I think you should be stubborn in wanting to find and fix it. :)   (though the bug could still be in some third party library, in which case you might be out of luck, unless the bug can be skirted by some amount of juggling).

Answer (score 2):

The trouble with free and top is they can show you a problem, but they give little help in fixing the problem.  Of the 100's or 1000's of lines of code that allocate memory, which ones are leaking?  This is where valgrind helps.

If this is for a company with a budget for tools, you might look at purify or other commercial tools.

Just for completeness I will mention the Boehm conservative garbage collecting memory allocator (which works for C and C++ code).  You can turn off GC and use GC_Free() and it becomes a leak detection tool.  Or you can leave GC enabled to automatically free memory when no longer used.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on which allocator you're using. The libc allocators (malloc, calloc, realloc) and the C++ allocators (new, delete) are probably using an optimization trick involving not releasing memory back to the OS. You see, if you ask malloc for some memory, use it, and then free it, it isn't necessarily being released back to the OS. Rather, if I ask malloc for memory, it is (most lily) getting much more then is necessary (because of page boundaries). That way, next time you need more memory, malloc just has it sitting around. Same thing with free. The memory is probably just added to mallocs memory pool, from which your later allocations are drawing.

So, your applications first few mallocs put memory very high, but then the pool is big enough to accommodate future allocations.

Comment: This is actually what I figured out myself (I mean the usage of system memory pools), but I could not find a method to trace the usage of memory from such memory pools; apparently 'free' and 'top' do not provide such 'internal' information'

Comment: @BaroneAshura: They can't. All they can see is the total allocated memory. I think GCC has some sort of malloc debugging mode where malloc and free will log allocations though.

Comment: sigh! I feared such an answer :( Will look into gcc options... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition of using `valgrind` you could also consider using [Boehm's conservative GC](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/); you probably want to compile it and configure it as a memory leak detector.

And you might even dare using Boehm's GC as your primary memory allocator.

BTW, looking into `/proc/1234/maps` could help you (where 1234 is the pid of your process).