# Strange memory behavior with std map and shared_ptr

Tags: linux, c++11, memory-leaks, 64-bit, gcc4.7

The code below provokes a strange memory behavior on my Debian machine.
Even after maps are cleared, htop shows that the program still uses a lot of memory, which makes me think there is a memory leak. The strange fact is that it only appears under some circumstances.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <1|0> " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "1 to insert in the second map and see the problem "
                "and 0 to not insert" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    bool insertion = atoi(argv[1]);
    std::map<uint64_t, std::shared_ptr<std::string> > mapStd;
    std::map<uint64_t, size_t> counterToSize;
    size_t dataSize = 1024*1024;
    uint64_t counter = 0;

    while(counter < 10000)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<std::string> stringPtr =
                std::make_shared<std::string>(dataSize, 'a');
        mapStd[counter] = stringPtr;

        if (insertion)
        {
            counterToSize[counter] = dataSize;
        }
        if (counter > 500)
        {
            mapStd.erase(mapStd.begin());
        }
        std::cout << "\rInserted chunk " << counter << std::flush;

        counter++;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << "Press ENTER to delete the maps" << std::endl;
    char a;
    std::cin.get(a); // wait for ENTER to be pressed

    mapStd.clear();   // clear both maps
    counterToSize.clear();

    std::cout << "Press ENTER to exit the program" << std::endl;

    std::cin.get(a); // wait for ENTER to be pressed
    return 0;
}
```

**Explanation:**

The code creates two maps on the stack (but issue is the same if they are created on the heap). It then inserts std::shared_ptr of strings to the first map. Each string has a size of 1MB. Once 500 strings are inserted, one deletes the first one for each new insert, so that the total memory used by the map is always equal to 500MB. When a total of 10000 strings have been inserted, the program waits for the user to press ENTER. If you launch the program and pass 1 as first argument, then, for each insertion in the first map, another insertion is also made to the second map. If the first argument is 0, then the second map is not used. Once ENTER is pressed for the first time, both maps are cleared. The program still runs and waits again for ENTER to be pressed, and then exits.

**Here are the facts:**

- On my 64-bit Debian 3.2.54-2, after ENTER is pressed (thus after the maps are cleared), and when the program is launched with 1 as first argument (thus with insertion in the second map), htop indicates that the program STILL USE 500MB OF MEMORY!! If the program is launched with 0 as first argument, then the memory is correctly released.
- This machine uses g++4.7.2 and libstdc++.so.6.0.17. I've tried with g++4.8.2 and libstdc++.so.6.0.18, same issue.
- I've tried on a 64bit Fedora 21 with g++4.9.2 and libstdc++.so.6.0.20, same issue.
- I've tried on an **32 bit** Ubuntu 14.04 with g++4.8.2 and libstdc++.so.6.0.19, the problem does NOT appear!
- I've tried on an **32 bit** Debian 3.2.54-2 with g++4.7.2 and libstdc++.so.6.0.17, the problem does NOT appear!
- I've tried on 64-bit Windows, the problem does NOT appear!
- On a machine where the problem exists, if you invert the lines where the maps are cleared (thus if you clear first the uint64_t, size_t map, the problem disappear!

Does somebody have an explanation for all this ???

Comment: The memory allocator is implemented by the C++ standard library, which with gcc uses libc's `malloc`. You should also include the version of libc you're using on each test machine. Windows, depending on compiler, probably has its own completely separate implementation.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53447/does-free-unmap-the-memory-of-a-process , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023815/memory-stability-of-a-c-application-in-linux , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232119/memory-usage-doesnt-decrease-when-free-used  , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend looking [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=cb91b97da46bc1e1f8afdfb718568ef193c2814a;hb=HEAD#l907) followed by [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=cb91b97da46bc1e1f8afdfb718568ef193c2814a;hb=HEAD#l2930). Basically, the libc malloc starts out by using mmap for "large" allocations (> 128k), and brk/freelists for small allocations. Once one of the large allocations is free'd, it tries to adjust the sizes where it might use malloc, but only if the size is less than the max (defined at that first link). In the 32 bit case, your strings are way above the max, so it continues to use mmap/munmap for the large allocations, and only puts the smaller map node allocations into memory retrieved from the system with sbrk. That's why you don't see the 'problem' on 32 bit systems.

The other bit is one of fragmentation and when free tries to coalesce memory and return it to the system. By default, free will just stick small blocks onto a free list so that they're ready to go for the next request. If a large enough block is free'd at the top of the heap, it will try to return memory to the system [see comment here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=cb91b97da46bc1e1f8afdfb718568ef193c2814a;hb=HEAD#l4025). The threshold is 64K.

Your allocation pattern in case where you pass `1` likely leaves some element of the `counterToSize` map near the top of the heap preventing it from being free'd by the last release of one of the strings. The releases of the various objects inside of the `counterToSize` map are not large enough to trigger the thresholds.

If you switch the order of your `.clear()` calls, you'll find that the memory is released like you'd expect. Also, if you were to allocate a large chunk of memory and immediately free it immediately after the clears, it'd trigger the release. (Large in this case just needs to be more than 128 bytes - the max sized used to trigger fast bins. (i.e. free's of that size and allocs less than that size just go onto the list.

I hope that was clear. Basically, it's not really a problem. You've got some pages mapped. You're not using anything on them, but the last free that might have released them was too small to trigger that code path. The next time you try to allocate something, it will pull from the memory you already have (you could do the whole loop again without growing memory).

Oh, and you could call `malloc_trim()` by hand and force it to do the coalescing/cleanup if you really needed the pages back at that point.

Comment: malloc_trim works, thanks for the tip. But allocating a chunk immediately after the clears doesn't trigger the release. I've tried with different sizes from 64 bytes to 10 MB...

Comment: When I add `int64_t* foo = new int64_t[16]; delete[] foo;` it ends up empty. Sizes smaller than 16 don't trigger because the allocation goes straight into a fastbin and skips all of the other logic. If it's larger than that, it gets merged with the nearby chunks, and then the size is checked before inserting it into a free list and triggering cleanup. If you just allocated the memory, you didn't trigger the release logic.